# How to create a Blob object from image url?

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am using Winjs(javascript for windows 8 app).
what I want is to create a simple blob object from a specific url of my static image by giving the path.
What is the solution?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'MSApp.CreateFileFromStorageFile()` as used below will work. if you need to send the file using WinJS.xhr() you can set as data in xhrOptions.

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appx:///images/IMG_0550.jpg');
        var self = this;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(function ongetfilecomplete(storageFile)
        {
            var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(storageFile);
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
            // assume that this.imageElement points to the image tag
            self.imageElement.setAttribute('src', url);
        }).then(null, function onerror(error)
        {

        });
```

refer the [link](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/03/22/uploading-image-to-azure-blob-from-windows-store-app/) in case you are looking for upload the blob to azure. For send the blob to your webservice also, code will be on these lines.

Comment: what i want exactly not to get a image file from Storage file (i don't want to add new capability ): how to instantantiate a blob object with an image in my /images folder or even an empty one Blob  , i need it to send with my web service

Answer (score 0):

URL.createObjectURL("") should work. I use it all the time. Test it with some other URLs. You could do it in debug mode in the JS console to make it easier.