# how to load blob from Windows.Storage.StorageFile WinJS

Tags: javascript, image, visual-studio-2012, blob, winjs

I am developing a metro app with WinJS which opens my camera, takes and creates a picture storing the result on a `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` object (*capturedItem*) I want to create from them a blob object

this is my method:

```
 function imageCapture() {

        var captureUI = new _capture.CameraCaptureUI();

        captureUI.photoSettings.format = _capture.CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.jpeg;
        captureUI.captureFileAsync(_capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo)
            .then(function (capturedItem) {
                if (capturedItem) {

                    var photoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
                        capturedItem,
                        { oneTimeOnly: true });

                    imageElement = document.createElement("img");
                    imageElement.id = "img1";
                    imageElement.setAttribute("src", photoBlobUrl);

                    _divPicture.appendChild(imageElement);

                    // prints in textfield blob value
                    document.getElementById("field1").value = capturedItem.path;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hope this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904374/how-to-create-a-blob-object-from-image-url

Answer (score 0):

You're actually pretty close. You should create a file from the capturedItem first. Like so:

```
var file = MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(capturedItem);
// than use the file variable in the createObjectURL function
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
var imageElement = document.createElement("img");
imageElement.id = "img1";
imageElement.setAttribute("src", url);
_divPicture.appendChild(imageElement);
```